# Find $f_Y(y)$ if $f_{X,Y}(x, y)=2e^{−x}e^{−y}$ for $x$ and $y$ defined over the shaded region.

Tags: probability

[image: The Given Picture]

I have no idea how to start this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For future reference, use `$f_{X,Y}(x, y)=2e^{−x}e^{−y}$` to show $f_{X,Y}(x, y)=2e^{−x}e^{−y}$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

A start: "Integrate out" $x$. Note that $x$ travels from $0$ to $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the the density is defined over
$$\{(x,y): y>x, x>0,y>0\}$$

To get the marginal density of $Y$, we must integrate out $X$. To do so, observe that $0<x<y$, and so
$$f_Y(y) = \int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx= \int_0^y 2e^{−x}e^{−y}\,dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

the picture means that : $ 0\leq x\leq y$ , 
$$ \int_{0}^{+ \infty }f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx=
\\\int_{0}^{+ \infty } 2 e^{-x}e^{-y}\mathbb{I}_{0\leq x\leq y}(x) \, dx =\int_0^y 2 e^{-x}e^{-y} \, dx =2 e^{-y}(1-e^{-y})$$